# AutoFixture AutoMoq Cast a mocked object as an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture, automoq

I hope someone can give me some ideas.

I need to create a mocked object that satisfies the following:

1. It implements the interface IEntity.
2. It uses the base implementation I already have in EntityBase.
3. The properties are auto generated with AutoFixture.

I have tried several alternatives and I ended with this code:

```
fixture.Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());

fixture.Customize<IEntity>(c => c.FromFactory(
     () => fixture.Create<Mock<EntityBase>>().As<IEntity>().Object));
```

However, I obtain the following exception:

Mock type has already been initialized by accessing its Object property. Adding interfaces must be done before that. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [`TypeRelay`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/b4a07c29828c6e9c540f9e4a2336f323a651b521/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/TypeRelay.cs) to tell AutoFixture that requests for `IEntity` should be satisfied by creating instances of `EntityBase`:

```
fixture.Customizations.Insert(0, new TypeRelay(typeof(IEntity), typeof(EntityBase)));
```

Now, every time AutoFixture has to create an instance of `IEntity`, it will instead create an instance of `EntityBase` which, in turn, will be handled by Moq thanks to the `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`.

Relays are pretty handy and there are [a few of them](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/b4a07c29828c6e9c540f9e4a2336f323a651b521/Src/AutoFixture/DefaultRelays.cs#L24-L31) built-in. In fact, they enable the whole auto-mocking functionality by [relaying](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/b4a07c29828c6e9c540f9e4a2336f323a651b521/Src/AutoMoq/MockRelay.cs) requests for interfaces and abstract classes to a mocking library.